# is it possible to attach the value in html elements like php have

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, logic, concept

just for increase my knowledge, i am asking this question to you.
do you think, its possible to attach the value in html elements like php.

let brief the example.
in php.

```
 <img src="<?php echo $imgSource ?>" title="<?php echo $imgSourceTitle ?>" >
```

can we do same in JavaScript or JQuery.
something like this.

```
<img src="javascript:$(this).val(imgSrc)" title="javascript:$(this).val(imgSrcTitle)" >
```

Comment: Not really, just set the attribute the JavaScript

Comment: can u brief little more @viham1086

Comment: javascript is not parsed like php. Also, in you example what is `$(this)` reference to, as right now it is out of scope.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to attach the values like that, because JavaScript code is not parsed like PHP and should be executed once the DOM is ready. To change DOM elements you can use jQuery inside the `$(document).ready()`function. Try something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#my_a").attr("href","http://google.it");
    $("#my_a").attr("title", "my_title");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="my_a">Test</a>
```

Note that the code is executed once the page is completely loaded, not at parsing time (like PHP does).